# How return var from callback function ? OOP property

Tags: javascript, oop, callback

```
var App = function(){
   this.db = [];
}
App.prototype.getJson = function(){
   var slef = this;
   $.getJSON('url', function(data){
       self.db.push(data);
     });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   var app = new App();
   console.log(app.db); //return []
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(app.db); //return data JSON
   }, 5000);
});
```

Why is this happening? How get property app.db without setTimeout?

AND

Can i return variable from callback function without constriction

```
appAPI.db.async.get(key, function(value) {
        var data = (value === null) ? null : JSON.parse(value);
        // invoke the callback and pass the results to it
        callback(data);
    });
```

and

```
LB.getData('user', function(data) {
    // use the data here
    alert(data.someProperty);
});
```

?

Comment: Because `$.getJSON` is not an instantaneous process.

Comment: Please stop dropping a bunch of `........`s at the end of your questions. Why are you doing that?

Comment: You've typod `slef` as `self` for one thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it cause because you do assync request, use promices to get value after request is end. http://api.jquery.com/promise/

```
setTimeout(function(){
     console.log(app.db); //return data JSON
}, 5000);
```

donot save you if request will be longer then 5sec

sample:

```
var App = function(){
   this.db = [];
}
var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
App.prototype.getJson = function(){
   var slef = this;
   $.getJSON('url', function(data){
       self.db.push(data);
       dfd.resolve(data);
     });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   var app = new App();
   console.log(app.db); //return []
   $.when( dfd.promise()).then(
      function( data) {
        console.log(app.db);
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Don't use your own promise. Just return the one jQuery is already giving you.

Comment: You're using them totally incorrectly. You're only showing him how to do it *wrong*. A) You declare a *global* `dfd`, which is wrong for all kinds of reasons. B) you use `$.when` for a single promise. C) You convert the deferred to a promise at the wrong point. The point of `.promise` is to return a promise from a function, while the deferred remains "private".

Comment: @meagar I agree that the structure of the code should be different, but washed away in that would show that there is a promise that we resolve later